# Delphi/FMX + iOS: UNUserNotificationCenter don't raises the delegate events (local notifications)

Tags: ios, delphi, notifications, firemonkey, unusernotificationcenter

I'm trying to reproduce the UNUserNotificationCenter (iOS10+) with Delphi/Firemonkey. The app successfully authorizes for receiving notifications and show all local notifications as expected, nowever UNUserNotificationCenter doesn't trigger the delegate events (e.g. when user taps on the notification item).

```
type
  UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate = interface(IObjectiveC)
    ['{817A2C54-2F1E-4322-8BDB-2E77F8FAB1AE}']
    procedure willPresentNotification(center: UNUserNotificationCenter; notification: UNNotification; completionHandler: TUserNotificationsWithCompletionHandler1); cdecl;
    procedure didReceiveNotificationResponse(center: UNUserNotificationCenter; response: UNNotificationResponse; completionHandler: TUserNotificationsWithCompletionHandler2); cdecl;
  end;
```

My delegate object:

```
type
  TUserNotificationCenterDelegate = class(TOCLocal, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate)
  public
    procedure willPresentNotification(center: UNUserNotificationCenter; notification: UNNotification; completionHandler: TUserNotificationsWithCompletionHandler1); cdecl;
    procedure didReceiveNotificationResponse(center: UNUserNotificationCenter; response: UNNotificationResponse; completionHandler: TUserNotificationsWithCompletionHandler2); cdecl;
  end;

var
  NotificationCenterDelegate: TUserNotificationCenterDelegate; 

implementation

[...]

function TfrmApplication.AppEventHandler(AAppEvent: TApplicationEvent; AContext: TObject): Boolean;
begin
  Result := true;

  case AAppEvent of
    TApplicationEvent.FinishedLaunching:
    begin
       UserNotificationCenterDelegate := TUserNotificationCenterDelegate.Create;
       TUNUserNotificationCenter.OCClass.currentNotificationCenter.setDelegate((UserNotificationCenterDelegate as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);   
       TUNUserNotificationCenter.OCClass.currentNotificationCenter.requestAuthorizationWithOptions(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound, nil);
    end;
    TApplicationEvent.EnteredBackground:
    begin
      DEF_APPLICATION_IN_BACKGROUND := true;
    end;
    TApplicationEvent.BecameActive:
    begin
      DEF_APPLICATION_IN_BACKGROUND := false;
      TUNUserNotificationCenter.OCClass.currentNotificationCenter.removeAllDeliveredNotifications;
    end;
  else
    Result := false;
  end;
end;
```

The events below should to be raised every time by when notification presents and the app is in foreground or when user taps the notification, respectively. But nothing happens.

```
procedure TUserNotificationCenterDelegate.willPresentNotification(center: UNUserNotificationCenter; notification: UNNotification; completionHandler: TUserNotificationsWithCompletionHandler1); cdecl;
var
  aImp: procedure(options: NSUInteger); cdecl;
  aOptions: UNNotificationPresentationOptions;
begin
  WriteLog(AP_LOG_HEADER + 'Will present notification');
  //completionHandler
  @aImp := imp_implementationWithBlock(completionHandler);
  aOptions := UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert;
  aImp(aOptions);
  imp_removeBlock(@aImp);
end;

procedure TUserNotificationCenterDelegate.didReceiveNotificationResponse(center: UNUserNotificationCenter; response: UNNotificationResponse; completionHandler: TUserNotificationsWithCompletionHandler2); cdecl;
var
  aImp: procedure(); cdecl;
begin
  WriteLog(AP_LOG_HEADER + 'Receive notification response');
  //completionHandler
  @aImp := imp_implementationWithBlock(completionHandler);
  aImp();
  imp_removeBlock(@aImp);
end;
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: You're missing MethodName attributes, as per UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate here: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/blob/master/API/DW.iOSapi.UserNotifications.pas.

Comment: @Dave I thought, that the MethodName attribute would only be important if the declaration of the event differs from the origininal framework declaration. In my case, the declaration of delegate methods is exactly the same from the UserNotifications.framework.

Comment: With MethodName it doesn't work also. Somewhere I missed something.

Comment: You might like to take a look at my implementation in the units here: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/tree/master/Features/Notifications

Comment: @Dave: Thank You Dave, Your library it's great, it works! The only issue is, that then app can't show two or more (local) notifications very quickly successively. The notifications will appear somehow like from the stack.